# Multilevel Analysis for count variable

Tags: multilevel-analysis, nested-data, intraclass-correlation, nested-models

I have a general question about multilevel analysis and have therefore created a minimal example to represent the data I want to analyse:

```
    forumname <- c("forum1", "forum1", "forum1", "forum2", "forum2", "forum2", "forum2", "forum2", "forum3", "forum3")

    posts <- c("Hi there.", "Hello, you.", "Welcome in forum 1.", "Hey forum 2, Im new here.",
                "That's cool.", "I was also new, once.", "I think we all were.", "Good point", 
               "Can I ask a question in forum 3?", "That depends on your question.")

    userkarma <- c(1,123,377,2,332,3345,43,222,2,323)

    postnumber <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2)

    forumdata <- data.frame(forumname, posts, userkarma, postnumber)
```

My goal would be to predict the position in the thread ("postnumber") from "userkarma", or rather to get numeric value for the relationship between karma and the relative time at which a user "joins" a forum.

As for my understanding of multilevel analysis, it would be legitimate to suppose that there are differences between forums regarding karma and therefore consider them to be nested within forums. Therefore it would feel natural to calculate an ICC (intraclass-correlation) which is (if I understand correctly) just a one-factor ANOVA with random factors, whereas these random are the level-2-units (the forums). With such a prodecure, I would get a measure for how much variance is due to differences within the forum, and how much is due to differences between forums.

However, if I want to predict the position in the forum, wouldn't I first have to check whether or not the variable "postnumber" is nested within the data by calculating ICC? How is that possible with "count"-data like I have it? And does it even make sense?

Also, would it be possible to suppose that my data is nested within threads first (of course supposing that one forum contains more than one thread), which would make every post a level-1-unit, every thread a level-2-unit and all forums level-3-units?

If anybody took the time to clear those things up about multilevel-modeling, I be really thankful, since I'm fairly new to it and also lacking resources.

[image: My example-dataframe in R-Studio]

---

Edit: Should I rather ask this question in the datascience forum or is this right for crossvalidated? Also, are there any other ways I can improve this question?

Comment: Cross Validated seems like the right place for it. ICCs are not clear with count outcomes and so you can test whether you need to account for nesting by running a likelihood ratio test (annova()) comparing a model estimated by glm (family = possion) and then one using glmmTMB() or perhaps GLMMadaptive(). As long as the link function and distribution is identical, these two models are nested within each other. Provided you have enough data you could have thread at level 2 with forum at level 1. Use likelihood ratio testing to see whether the 3-level model fits better than a 2-level model.